# Как получить список диалогов пользователя из базы всех сообщений используя Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, linq, entity-framework-core

У меня есть таблица в базе с сообщениями, а именно:

`| Id | FromId | ToId | Text | Date | Read |`

Вот как выглядит класс:

```cs
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser From { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser To { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }
}
```

Мне нужно сформировать запрос на получение списка всех диалогов пользователя средствами Entity Framework Core. Я набросал примерный SQL запрос:

```sql
SELECT FromId, MAX(Date) as updated_at, sum(Read) as new_messages 
FROM (SELECT FromId, Date, Read 
FROM Messages 
WHERE ToId = 'f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537' 
UNION SELECT ToId, Date, 0 
FROM Messages 
WHERE FromId = 'f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537' 
ORDER BY Date DESC) as talks 
GROUP BY FromId 
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

где `'f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537'` - это Id пользователя, список диалогов которого я хочу получить.

Однако я не могу выполнить его используя Entity Framework (или не знаю как). Есть ли какой-то способ сделать подобное используя только EF. Я использую SQLite.

Comment: `From` != `FromId`, `To` != `ToId`. `Однако я не могу выполнить его` - как вы это поняли?

Comment: При создании запроса в EF, все мои From и To в коде заменятся на FromId и ToId в SQL. А как я могу его выполнить, если у меня нет определенной сущности для результата запроса. А отдельную таблицу под это создавать я не хочу.

Comment: При составлении запроса в EF думайте сущностями, а не SQL запросами. `нужно сформировать запрос на получение списка всех диалогов пользователя`, значит результирующим набором должен быть список экземпляров Message: `db.Messages.Where(x => x.From.Equlas(id) or x.To.Equlas(id))` отсюда и начните.

Comment: Да это понятное дело. И я прекрасно понимаю, как получить набор сообщений конкретного пользователя. Мне нужно как-то с помощью LINQ указать, что набор полей From и To был уникальным. То есть если встречается что From = 1 и To = 2, то значит не должно быть From = 2 и To = 1.

Comment: Сделайте пример кода, который можно скопировать и запустить. То есть должно быть создание БД и заполнение её данными. Тогда вы можете быстро получить ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ запрос пишется точно также как и SQL, только надо разделять его на маленькие "запчасти", которые потом и склеиваются в результирующую выборку.

```cs
var userId = new Guid("f3578a36-208c-4504-8f3c-afa564455537");

var mssagesTo = 
    from m in ctx.Messages
    where m.ToId == @useerId
    select new {
        UserId = m.FromId,
        Date = m.Date,
        Read = m.Read ? 1 : 0
    };

var mssagesFrom = 
    from m in ctx.Messages
    where m.FromId == @useerId
    select new {
        UserId = m.ToId,
        Date = m.Date,
        Read = 0
    };

var messages = mssagesTo.Union(mssagesFrom);

var query = 
    from m in messages
    group m by m.UserId into g
    select new {
        UserId = g.Key,
        Date = g.Max(x => x.Date),
        Read = g.Sum(x => x.Read)
    };

query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```